# IIS Deployment and Hosting for OfficeJS using VSCode with typescript

Tags: office-js

We developed sample project with API call in Excel Add-in with custom functions Batching in OfficeJS using VScode. Now wanted to deploy into IIS for hosting. Kindly provide the steps for web deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You host your add-in just like any other web app, so we don't have special instructions for doing that, except [Package your add-in using Visual Studio to prepare for publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/package-your-add-in-using-visual-studio). You also need to deploy the manifest. See [Deploy and publish your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish).

Comment: Hi, We were trying to deploy into IIS or node js server but little confusing which one to use dedicately since we are using web pack config.js file where all url's referring. Any References will be helpful.